# div dragger is working fine on jsfiddle but not on testing server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a div dragger which works perfectly fine in jsfiddle...
but when i tried it on testing server it is not working..
what is the problem i am not getting...

i had tried the code which is on jsfiddle...

jsfiddle code link [div dragger](http://jsfiddle.net/brahdian/cF2bT/)

testing server link...
[here](http://natwet.hostei.com/Elunika)

`email for login: test@test.com`

`password for login: test1234`

Comment: Look in the error console for error messages.

Comment: it is saying: `Object [object Object] has no method 'drags`
then why it is working perfectly in jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your function call for #yes *inside* document.ready.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.drags = function(opt) {
        ...
    }

    $('#yes').drags();
});
```

Comment: this is the correct answer. the fiddle javascript is already wrapped in the `ready()` function. if you type `$('#yes').drags();` into the console you'll notice it works.